# Ins key on a mac keyboard in Linux

Tags: linux, macos, keyboard

I am on a Linux (fluxbox/Mint) with `urxvt` using an external Mac keyboard. I can't find an `ins` key. In `urxvt` you can select a part of text, it automatically copies, and with other types of keyboards I could use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and it pastes the text. How can I paste the text with a mac keyboard running in a Linux? Needless to say, that I tried the standard variations of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, in combination with <kbd>fn</kbd> key.

Answer (score 3):

Try <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>.

This works as middle-click paste under both Gnome (Wayland) and i3wm (Xorg) in Fedora 28 with my 2016 MacBook Pro 13,1 built-in keyboard (using an out-of-tree SPI driver). Hopefully it's the same situation for external Mac keyboards under other specific environments.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd> to simulate the `Insert` key.

Another way, install `AutoKey` :

```
apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

and set a phrase to:

```
Phrase Text: <ctrl>+C (actually type out the <ctrl>+ here)
Paste Using: Keyboard
Abbreviation: None
Hotkey: <super>+v
Window Filter: None
```

If you want to use your Apple keyboard like a regular US-layout keyboard, with <kbd>Alt</kbd> on the left side of `Meta`, you can use the AUR package `un-apple-keyboard`. Currently it only works for the aluminium USB model.

The package does the following things:

- Adds a `/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` file which enables the <kbd>F num</kbd> keys by default, as in #Function keys do not work.
- Uses keyfuzz to remap <kbd>F13-15</kbd> to <kbd>PrintScreen/SysRq</kbd>, <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, and <kbd>Pause</kbd>, respectively.
- Swaps the ordering of the `Alt` and `Meta (Command)` keys to match all other keyboards, again using `/etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf`, as in #Swap the Alt key and Command key (Meta/Super).
- Applies these changes automatically when you plug in your keyboard, with a udev rule.

See more information from Archlinux wiki [Apple Keyboard](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apple_Keyboard).

Comment: On my Macbook Air running Debian, the `paste` key combo is `fn` + `shift` + `return`.

Answer (score 1):

Try Fn+Opt+Return. Works for me.

Comment: this reply sends the right keycode. So you can switch from insert to replace mode, etc, like a regular keyboard. Tested on a magic keyboard with numeric pad

Comment: also, if you swap option with command keys with the hid_apple module parameters, this becomes fn+command+return, and it still works OK.

Answer (score 0):

I have bluetooth [Satechi X1](https://satechi.net/products/slim-x1-bluetooth-backlit-keyboard) which are Mac keyboard and there is no <kbd>Insert</kbd> key on it. I have need to use <kbd>Insert</kbd>  to paste from clipboard to Ubuntu Gnome Terminal.

Some guys saying that <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> doing <kbd>Insert</kbd> and **this is true**. The problem that guys are trying to use **wrong sequence of keys** when they are trying to Insert from Clipboard into Ubuntu Gnome terminal.

So the sequence to make insert to terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + (<kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>RETURN</kbd>) will be exactly this one:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>
2. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>
3. <kbd>FN</kbd>
4. <kbd>RETURN</kbd>

**Then you will insert from clipboard!!!**